# How to limit length for a specific innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

My code is made to shuffle text and create a random suite of characters.
I would like to limit the length generated by the shuffle to the numbers of characters included in the innerHTML.
example : HOME, shuffle only 4 characters and not more
          STUDIES, shuffle onle the all 7 characters and not more
          ..... etc.

Here's the code

```js
// Shuffle
jQuery(function($) {
    function text_shuffle() {
        "use strict";
        var counter = 0, all = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789*?><[]&@#)(.%$-_:/;?!";
         $_inter = setInterval(function() {
            var text = document.getElementById("text-shuffle");
            text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.substring(0, counter) + all.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*all.length)) + text.innerHTML.substring(counter+1);
            counter = (counter+1)%text.innerHTML.length;
        }, 150);
    }
    var value, $_inter;

    $("#text-shuffle").mouseenter( function(){
        value  = $(this).html();
        text_shuffle();
    }).
    mouseout(function(){
        clearInterval($_inter);
        $(this).html(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text-shuffle">title1</div>
```

Comment: Is requirement to shuffle the existing `.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close (and actually a pretty slick thing you are doing).  The issue is that some of the characters in the substitution do wacky things (`>`, `<`, and `&` in particular).

I saw that you were using jQuery so I modified the way the text is extracted and replaced in the shuffle div.

```js
// Shuffle
jQuery(function($) {
    function text_shuffle() {
        "use strict";
        var counter = 0, all = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789*?><[]&@#)(.%$-_:/;?!";
         $_inter = setInterval(function() {
            var text = $("#text-shuffle").text();
            text = text.substring(0, counter) + all.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*all.length)) + text.substring(counter+1);
            $("#text-shuffle").text(text);
            counter = (counter+1)%text.length;
        }, 150);
    }
    var value, $_inter;

    $("#text-shuffle").mouseenter( function(){
        value  = $(this).html();
        text_shuffle();
    }).
    mouseout(function(){
        clearInterval($_inter);
        $(this).html(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text-shuffle">title1</div>
```